# Objective C: JQuery cannot find $ in UIWebView

Tags: jquery, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I'm just trying to get a webpage to `UIWebView`, to have a local version which works without internet.

But it seems like `jQuery` isn't loading.

[image]

I tested this with an onClickfunction like

```
<script>                       
    function testfunction(){

        $('#test').hide();

        if ($("#test").length > 0){
           alert("exist");
        }
    }
</script>
```

I embed `jQuery` like:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascript_9a38f34785.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All files are in the `mainBundle`

I`m loading local ressource like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myhtmlfile" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    [viewWeb loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];

}
```

Anyone any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a check here

1. Project Navigator (Cmd + 1)
2. Select your project
3. Select target
4. Select "Build Phases" tab, there you will get your desire sections.
5. Add desired js file to copy bundle resources